# sencha touch hide and show layout

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a multiple layouts in container as shown

```
items:[{
       layout:{....},
       id:'firstLayout',
       items:[....]
    },{
       layout: {....},
       id:'secondLayout',
       hidden:true,
       items: [...]
  }]
```

at run time when I do something I need to hide first layout and show second.
how i do this ?

Comment: Why don't you use card layout? http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.Card

Comment: What determines the view hiding and another showing? User input or an event?

Comment: you can use card layout or manually you can hide and show component. you can get that compoent using component query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [card](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.Card) layout is the thing you are looking for.

Here's a nice little descriptive tutorial (not by sencha and definitely not by me, some random site that I found when I did google...) - http://html5wood.com/sencha-touch-2-card-layout/